# loggly with winston set tags dynamically

Tags: node.js, winston, loggly

I'm using loggly with node js. This is the initialization script:

```
var winston  = require('winston');
require('winston-loggly-bulk');

winston.add(winston.transports.Loggly, {
    inputToken: "TOKEN",
    subdomain: "SUBDOMAIN",
    tags: ["Winston-NodeJS"],
    json:true
});
```

It looks like the tags are set on `winston.add` initialization, but what if I want to set some tag dynamically when I send a message to the logger?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [**winston-loggly-bulk** source](https://github.com/loggly/winston-loggly-bulk/blob/master/lib/winston-loggly.js#L117), it is possible to include tags in the [metadata of the logging instruction](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#logging-with-metadata) using the `tags` property.  For example:

```
logger.log('info', 'Server starting up.', { tags: 'server' });
```

The value can be [either a single tag or an array](https://github.com/loggly/winston-loggly-bulk/blob/master/lib/winston-loggly.js#L46), like this:

```
logger.log('info', 'Server starting up.', { tags: ['server', 'startup'] });
```